# How to open and read files line-by-line from a directory?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to read file lines from a directory containing about 200 text files, however, I can't get Ruby to read them line-by-line. I did it before, using one text file, not reading them from a directory.

I can get the file names as strings, but I am struggling to open them and read each line.

Here are some of the methods I've tried.

Method 1:

```
def readdirectory
  @filearray = []
Dir.foreach('mydirectory') do |i|
 # puts i.class
    @filearray.push(i)
    @filearray.each do |s|
     # @words =IO.readlines('s')
      puts s
    end#do
 #   puts @words
end#do

end#readdirectory
```

Method 2:

```
def tryread
 Dir.foreach('mydir'){
   |x| IO.readlines(x)
 }

end#tryread
```

Method 3:

```
def tryread
 Dir.foreach('mydir') do |s|
   File.readlines(s).each do |line|
               sentence =line.split
   end#inner do

 end #do
end#tryread
```

With every attempt to open the string passed by the loop function, I keep getting the error:

```
Permission denied - . (Errno::EACCES)
```

Comment: So you don't have permissions to read the files.

Comment: +1 for what @SergioTulentsev said. The error code spells out the main/first problem. Instead of `readlines` look at `File.foreach` as it's more scalable in #2 and #3.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo ruby reader.rb` or whatever your filename is.

Since permissions are process based you can not read files with elevated permissions if the process reading does not have them.

Only solutions are either to run the script with more permissions or call another process which is already running with higher permissions to read for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all replies,I did a bit of trial and error and got it to work.This is the syntax I used

```
    Dir.entries('lemmatised').each do |s|
      if !File.directory?(s)

        file = File.open("pathname/#{s}", 'r')

        file.each_line do |line|
          count+=1
          @words<<line.split(/[^a-zA-Z]/)
        end # inner do
            puts @words
      end #if
    end #do
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
#it'll hold the lines
f = []

#here test directory contains all the files,
#write the path as per the your computer,
#mine's as you can see, below

#fetch filenames and keep in sorted order
a = Dir.entries("c:/Users/lordsangram/desktop/test")

#read the files, line by line
Dir.chdir("c:/Users/lordsangram/desktop/test")

#beginning for i = 1, to ignore first two elements of array a,
#which has no associated file names
2.upto(a.length-1) do |i|
    File.readlines("#{a[i]}").each do |line|
        f.push(line)
    end  
end

f.each do |l|
    puts l
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@the Tin Man -> you need to avoid processing "." and ".." which are listed in `Dir.foreach` and give the permission denied error. A simple `if` should fix all your apporoaches.

```
Dir.foreach(ARGV[0]) do |f|
  if f != "." and f != ".."
    # code to process file
    # example
    # File.open(ARGV[0] + "\\" + f) do |file|
    # end
  end
end
```